# Jquery clone function creates duplicated image on drag and drop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm working on a drag and drop application using jQuery.

However, the issue that I have is that when I drag and drop the images, it duplicates the images.

I did try to remove the given class like so: `ui.helper.removeClass("draggable");`

but I still see the image duplicated and I don't understand what's causing this issue.

This is my entire code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <style type="text/css">
        body
        {
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size: 10pt;
        }
        #dvSource img
        {
            height: 100px;
            width: 100px;
            margin: 2px;
        }
        .draggable
        {
            filter: alpha(opacity=60);
            opacity: 0.6;
        }
        .dropped
        {
            position: static !important;
        }
        #dvSource, #dvDest
        {
            border: 5px solid #ccc;
            padding: 5px;
            min-height: 100px;
            width: 430px;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.24/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.24/themes/blitzer/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"
        type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#dvSource img").draggable({
                revert: "invalid",
                refreshPositions: true,
                drag: function (event, ui) {
                    ui.helper.addClass("draggable");
                },
                stop: function (event, ui) {
                    ui.helper.removeClass("draggable");
                    var image = this.src.split("/")[this.src.split("/").length - 1];
                    if ($.ui.ddmanager.drop(ui.helper.data("draggable"), event)) {
                        //alert(image + " dropped.");
                    }
                    else {
                        alert(image + " not dropped.");
                    }
                }
            });
            $("#dvDest").droppable({
                drop: function (event, ui) {
                    if ($("#dvDest img").length == 0) {
                        $("#dvDest").html("");

                    }
                    ui.helper.removeClass("draggable");
                    ui.draggable.addClass("dropped");
                    //$("#dvDest").append(ui.draggable).clone();
                    $("#dvDest").append($(ui.draggable).clone());






                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    <div id="dvSource">
        <img alt="" src="images/Chrysanthemum.jpg" />
        <img alt="" src="images/Desert.jpg" />
        <img alt="" src="images/Hydrangeas.jpg" />
        <img alt="" src="images/Jellyfish.jpg" />
        <img alt="" src="images/Koala.jpg" />
        <img alt="" src="images/Lighthouse.jpg" />
        <img alt="" src="images/Penguins.jpg" />
        <img alt="" src="images/Tulips.jpg" />
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div id="dvDest">
        Drop here
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

could someone please advise on this issue?

Comment: append the original and don't clone it?

Comment: @charlietfl, I need to clone it so It doesn't clear it off from the original div "dvSource".

Comment: ui.draggable is already a jQuery object. You don't need to wrap it in $(ui.draggable) again

Comment: @nanndoj, can you elaborate on that please?

Comment: In that case it is entirely unclear what your issue is

Comment: @charlietfl, the issue is that when I drag and drop the image inside the dvSource, I get 2 of the same image that I dragged and dropped.

Comment: please create a demo that replicates problem

Comment: It was just a tip. You can just call ui.dragable.clone() instead of $(ui.draggable).clone()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that function is being called twice here:

```
if($.ui.ddmanager.drop(ui.helper.data("draggable"), event)) {
....
```

jQuery already call drop but you are calling it again manually. It is not the right way to check the event but it calls the event again. Just remove that `if...else` clause that you code will work like a charm!

You are also warping an object into $() but the object is also an jquery object. you don't need to do it

```
// NOT $("#dvDest").append($(ui.draggable).clone());
$("#dvDest").append(ui.draggable.clone());
```